# Jquery mobile: Need check box and collapsible content

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am developing an application using jquery mobile where I need to display a list of records with check box and collapsible button.

By clicking the check box user can select multiple records.
By clicking collapsible button he can view record detail.

I fond below code on internet but its not working:

```
 <ul data-role=”listview”>
     <li class="ui-li-1line-check2">
        <span class="ui-li-text-main">1line-check2</span>
        <form><input type="checkbox" name="c1line-check2"/></form>
       <div data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="plus" data-style="circle">  </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Thanks!

Comment: All you have above is HTML - there is no JavaScript - this will just display a `checkbox` and a `button` ... nothing more

Comment: Can any one suggest any alternate way to achive above requirment.